# How to use qiskit.utils.QuantumInstance API of qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming, simulation

I am quite struggling with the usage of `QuantumInstance` API.
This API is present in `qiskit version 0.32.1`
Below is small code:

```
from qiskit.utils import QuantumInstance 
from qiskit import Aer
simulator_used = "qasm_simulator"
backend = Aer.get_backend(simulator_used)



quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(backend = backend,
                                   shots = 2000,
                                   seed_simulator= 28,
                                   seed_transpiler = 28,
                                   basis_gates = None,
                                   optimization_level =1)
```

Suppose, I want to make a simulator as `statevector_simulator`. Then do I have to make shots =1?

Suppose I want to use the `QuantumInstance` in the code below. Then how should I modify the code below? If `QuantumInstance` cannot be used in the code below, then where should it be used?

```
from qiskit import Aer
from qiskit import execute
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit


circ = QuantumCircuit(3,3)
circ.h(0)
circ.cx(0,1)
circ.cx(0,2)

backend = Aer.get_backend("qasm_simulator")  

job = execute(circ, backend, shots = 100000)
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts(circ)
print(counts)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `statevector_simulator`, you should generally set `shots=1`. The statevector simulator gives you the exact quantum state vector, which represents a deterministic outcome. Running it multiple times doesn't add additional information.

Here's how you would modify your code to use `QuantumInstance`:

```python
from qiskit.utils import QuantumInstance 
from qiskit import Aer

# ... (your circuit definition)

simulator_used = "statevector_simulator"  # Change for statevector
backend = Aer.get_backend(simulator_used)

quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(backend=backend,
                                   shots=1,  # 1 shot for statevector
                                   seed_simulator=28,
                                   seed_transpiler=28)

job = quantum_instance.execute(circ)  # Use QuantumInstance to execute
result = job.result()

# With the statevector simulator, get the statevector directly
statevector = result.get_statevector(circ)
print(statevector)
```

Comment: Thank for the response @davidryan. I think, `result = job.result()` should be replaced with `result = job.results`. printing result will give `[ExperimentResult(shots=1, success=True, meas_level=2, data=ExperimentResultData(counts={'0x0': 1}, statevector=[0.70710678+0.j 0.        +0.j 0.        +0.j 0.        +0.j
 0.        +0.j 0.        +0.j 0.        +0.j 0.70710678+0.j]), ....................]`. Now how to get statevector out of this list?

Comment: `result = job.result()` gives me the error: `AttributeError: Attribute result is not defined`

Comment: QuantumInstance was designed to give a common execution capability to algorithms from Qiskit Aqua which were moved into Qiskit and later all refactored to use Primitives (and now are also moved out of Qiskit into their own repo). QuantumInstance was deprecated, along with the old algorithms that used it, with the change to primitives. It is no longer in the latest Qiskit, and unless you had old code where you wanted to see that run, I would recommend not even trying to use it - well you can't with the latest Qiskit version!

Comment: Thank you for the response @SteveWood. I have this code: `from qiskit.algorithms import VQE`  `vqe = VQE(ansatz=ansatz_opt, 
                optimizer= optimizer,
                quantum_instance=quantum_instance,
                initial_point=initial_point_values
                )` where it needs quantum instance. I am not sure how to replace it or replace exactly with what?

Comment: That is the old VQE that did take a QuantumInstance. The latest VQE is in Qiskit Algorithms  now - here is a tutorial showing VQE - there are others too https://qiskit-community.github.io/qiskit-algorithms/tutorials/01_algorithms_introduction.html. It uses an Estimator primitive to do the quantum computation now, rather than how it did things before which was more directly executing circuits itself via the QuantumInstance.